# Bookmarks API on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, api

Is there any API on Internet Explorer to retrieve the users' bookmarks with javascript ?

thanks,

Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That would be a huge security hole. You could do it with ActiveX if you are, for example, working in a corporate intranet environment on IE, or with an extension if you are targeting a specific browser (such as Firefox or Chrome).

**EDIT** Reviewing your other questions, I realise you are asking if there is a way of doing it specifically for IE, **with the user's permission**. You could write an ActiveX control which get's the information for you. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/iefavorites.aspx for an example. I don't know of a way to do it through JavaScript directly though.

Comment: No way to do it directly from JS. IE6 had a way (window.external.ImportExportFavorites) to trigger an upload of the favorites to a server with the user's permission but that method was neutered in IE6 on XPSP2 and never was reenabled.